# Please explain me something with x11 cursor files

Tags: xorg, themes, cursor

why there are so many files for one cursor theme using x11 cursors? I mean I can find at least 3 files containing the same hand for links, when on windows .cur files do not repeat, why is this, do you need all x11 files to be changed?

[image]